# VB Webbrowser out of date

Tags: vb.net, bing-maps, bing

When ever I load any of my programs which use bing maps online it tells me my browser is out of date, even though it should rendering on the same version on internet explorer as the one on the computer which is current, any idea on fixing the problem?

Comment: Did you check (using Fiddler) which browser string is sent by your webbrowser control?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little lost never heard of Fiddler?

Comment: You should [give it a try](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) then. Tracing request and response usually clears thing up pretty fast. I your case I suspect a browser string for a (much) lower version is sent with your request.

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading the new Bing Maps consumer website, this is to be expected as it uses HTML5 and the WebBrowser control in .NET emulates IE7 I believe. That said, you shouldn't be using the consumer site inside of an app. There are two much better options. The first is the Bing Maps WPF control which you can use easily with VB without a WebBrowser control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx

Another option, if you want to use a WebBrowser control, is to use the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control which provides a full development API and works on IE6 and above: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx That said, you really should use the WPF version of Bing Maps as it would allow you to do all your development in VB.